# Micro applications using Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, microservices

I'm looking for an architecture solution that will help us develop different projects without dependencies(in development mode or production).

We have 4 different isolated  projects that  all of them is part of SPA Monolith application but our release times are different.

Currently, every team build their  Angular 2  module and publish it to NPM(The typescript.)

The Shell(orchestration project) consume all the applications, compile them into Javascript and only then we can deploy.

The thing is that every time that one of the projects want to deploy there is a "downtime" for all of the application(because we need to change the package.json and consume the new project and then download the new monolith files).

BTW,We're using Angular CLI for building our projects.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: why do you mean by isolated here ?

Comment: Give them the ability to consume whatever they want and to deploy to production whenever they want.Isolation in process

Comment: Every project will have its own set of package.json right?

Comment: Yes,every project will have its on package.json and its on routes.once one project want to deploy he will update the shell project to consume his latest version and deploy

Comment: How do those projects interact? Or, do they interact at all?

Comment: They interact via redux(actions and store)

Comment: Does each of them use their own redux stores, or you have one store for all the modules? If you have just one store, you need to isolate them.

Comment: hi.. did you find any solution ??